# Differential Equations Bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Q1]

What does it mean when it says the solutions become unbounded in finite time? How do solutions that look bounded look like. I don't really understand how this question relates back to the generalized equation r^2 = x^2 + y^2

Comment: This means that exists a finite time $t_0$ such that $|x(t)| \underset{t \to t_0^-}\to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

(a)

The equilibrium points are those such that $x' = y' = 0\;$

Considering the linearised approximation about $(0,0)$ we have

$$
x' = y\\
y' = -x
$$

which gives the orbits

$$
(r^2)' = 0 \Rightarrow r = C_0
$$

because $\frac 12(r^2)' = x\frac{dx}{dt}+y\frac{dy}{dt} \;$ characterizing a center.

(b)

Multiplying respectively by $x, y\;$ and adding we have

(1)
$$
x\frac{dx}{dt}+y\frac{dy}{dt} = (x^2+y^2)^2\Rightarrow \frac 12 (r^2)' = r^4
$$

(2)
$$
x\frac{dx}{dt}+y\frac{dy}{dt} = -(x^2+y^2)^2\Rightarrow \frac 12 (r^2)' = -r^4
$$